# Emulator doesn't connect to internet

Tags: android, dns, android-emulator

I know there are many questions about this, but none of provided answers is working for me.

I have a PC connected to internet by ethernet and by wifi. (I tried disabling wifi when i wasn't connected to it, but that didn't work either and i ended up connected in both ways)

I tried starting emulator with -dns-server flag, restarting pc, reinstalling emulator, but no help here neither.

What is strange about it is that only one android emulator actually works. It's a Nexus_5X_API_23
Neither works another nexus with other sdk, neither do any other phone with same sdk.

I tried starting emulator with -verbose flag and i don't really know what am i looking for, but both emulators (working and not working) have same arg[02] -dns-server

I've been trying to solve this for 2 days now, so i would really appreciate any help.

EDIT: I found out that only emulators with CPU/ABI = x86_64 works
None of x86 work tho. 
How can this be related?